# anybody know about "sql error" while loading csv file using pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I am loading CSV file using the panda's library from the local path  for machine learning. I am getting this error:

> ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'DATABASES' at line 1

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier # Import Decision Tree Classifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split # Import train_test_split function
from sklearn import metrics #Import scikit-learn metrics module for accuracy calculation

data=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\clorder\Desktop\python\prakash1.csv",)
print(data)
```

[Screenshot of the error in Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7sGW.png)

Comment: Just wondering, looks like an error that has nothing to do with pandas maybe, if you comment the lines where you are reading the csv and printing it, does it still crash? Also when you call the read_csv there is a coma at the end and no parameter after the path?

Answer (score 1):

Try data=pd.read_csv("C:\Users\clorder\Desktop\python\prakash1.csv") without coma at the end.